# How to monitor JMX events with Nagios?

Tags: monitoring, jmx, nagios

I know that we can monitor JMX Mbean attributes using the different nagios plugins. How to monitor JMX Notification Events that get generated?

Is there any open source solution to listen to these events and extract information from them?

Comment: The hardest part of this is parsing the incoming notifications to convert them into something nations can understand. So what will your notifications contain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exist indeed some interesting JVM metrics which are transmitted via JMX notifications (e.g. when a garbage collection happens), but most information is also available as plain JMX attributes (mostly aggregated then).

If you nevertheless need to monitor (e.g. custom) notifications with Nagios you have currently two options, both need some programming efforts:

- Write an own MBean which internally registers as a `NotificationListener` and collects the events in some form. Then a Nagios plugin can poll this information from an MBean`s attribute or operation during an active check. This is easy to implement, but of course the notifications are not delivered *in time*.
- Write a Java Class which registers as `NotificationListener` within your Java application and which contacts directly the Nagios server when a notification happens. There you would need also an extra setup for feeding in the received information into a passive check.

That said, [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org) 2.0 and [Jmx4Perl](http://www.jmx4perl.org)'s 2.0 Nagios Plugin will have support for  notifications in the one way or other. However, the release date is not yet fixed and it might take still some time (possibly not this year anymore).